# How to access a REST api from a Java application hosted by Elastic Beanstalk that is behind AWS VPC?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, vpc

I created an Elastic Beanstalk environment with a AWS VPC. It is a Java REST application using Spring framework.

When I setup the Elastic Beanstalk environment *without* a VPC, I'm able to hit the REST endpoint.

http://my-service.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/swagger-ui.html

However, now with VPC, I'm not able to access it.

What is the proper way to access this REST endpoint now?

Comment: You need to configure your EC2 instances to allow connections from the outside world.  AFAIK you still just have a bunch of EC2 instances behind your beanstalk setup.